# Typescript file imports being appended with .js extensions intermittently

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have setup a [Create T3 App](https://github.com/t3-oss/create-t3-app) and in certain `.ts` files in my project, when I go to import another `.ts` file the auto import/intellisense option for the import adds a `.js` file extension.

The same import made in another `.ts` file in the same directory or another directory, most of the time will not append the `.js` file extension.

Sometimes, in the `.ts` file(s) that appends the `.js` file extension on the auto import, when I remove all of the code and then try the import again, it does not append the `.js` extension. But if I close the file and re-open it again, it will once again. But this is intermittent.

I've Commented out all of my `settings.json` file, so uses the default settings

I've already restarted VSCode with Extensions Disabled

See Videos below for issue

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20436343/210012132-a6682005-5d22-485b-9e1b-cf617f3ffd1f.mov

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20436343/210012161-49604216-5ff5-4ee9-b0f8-de3b83458857.mov

Not sure how much the `tsconfig.json` file can affect this but this is my ts config.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true /* Report errors on unused locals. */,
    "noUnusedParameters": true /* Report errors on unused parameters. */,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "types/**/*.ts", "next-auth.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "**/*.js", "**/*.cjs", "**/*.mjs"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

- VS Code Version: 1.74.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's causing this problem, but you can try the following to see if that will force VS Code to use minimal path endings:

1. Open the command palette, `CTRL + shift + P`
2. Select `> Preferences: Open User Settings`.
3. Search for `Typescript Import Module Specifier Ending` in settings.
4. The default in my VS Code was `Auto`, Change this to `minimal`.

And if you want this setting to always apply to your project, add it in `.vscode/settings.json`

```json
{
  "typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifierEnding": "minimal"
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That seems to have fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

thanks I set setting to "js /ts" and it shown all imports with extension at the end as I want

like inside file : `index.ts`

```
import { class} from "./filename.js";
```